# Как сделать рандомный вычитатель чисел?

Tags: javascript, php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать рандомное уменьшение числа в определённый промежуток времени? Т.е. есть, к примеру, число 1000 (может быть любое число) надо чтобы из него рандомно вычитались числа от 1 до 7 (могут быть любые числа) с периодичностью в 10 - 90 минут (могут быть любые интервалы) пока от 1000 не останется 0. И выводить результат на странице сайта. 
Совершенно не понимаю как это сделать правильно. Заранее спасибо.
То что я смогла придумать:

```
$rand = rand(0, 7);
$kolvo = 1000;
echo $kolvo - $rand;
```

Comment: То есть у Вас своего рода вэб-приложение и манипулировать числом нужно на стороне сервера, а на клиенте обновлять данные, верно? Не помню точно, но кажется Вам стоит гуглить в сторону планирования задач. И конечно число придётся хранить на диске, а не в переменных php-скрипта. Думаю БД или просто файл придётся использовать. Ну а обновления клиентской части уже так: либо JS-скрипт периодически просит число GET-запросом, либо сервер отправляет число всем клиентам через WebSocket. Ну или число обновится только с обновлением страницы. К сожалению я не знаю PHP, но материал для гугления - вот он

Comment: Но только не GET-запросом, POST-запросом, во избежание кеширования.

Answer (score 1):

Если счетчик единый для всех пользователей сайта, и нам известны все данные (диапазон декремента и интервалов), то я бы заранее подсчитал случайные значения всех интервалов и сколько отнимать на каждом шаге. При первом вызове скрипта генерируем и записываем все эти данные в файл или БД. При последующих вызовах просто сравниваем текущую дату (timestamp) из списка и выводим соответствующее ей число.

Comment: Да, счётчик единый для всех. Я думаю, Ваш вариант оптимальный. Только как это отобразить с помощью кода?